# Read data from external biometric fingerprint device in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want to read biometric data from external biometric fingerprint device in flutter and want to store it in database and again want to match it when user scan their finger.

Comment: Talk to the device manufacturer and ask them what SDK they have for Android.

Comment: then wrap the sdk and make a plugin

Comment: Yes we can can achieve it using bridge.
Can you recommend best manufacturer?